# Magento: Does Mage::getModel('catalog/category') Use EAV or Flat Data?

Tags: magento

When you call `Mage::getModel('catalog/category')` or `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')`, does that load from the flat data or the `_entity` table?

There is an option in the admin that let you "use flat" data, and I'm wondering if this is related to the `::getModel()` call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `catalog/category` model is an EAV model.  In a default Magento configuration, its data is stored in

```
catalog_category_entity
catalog_category_entity_datetime
catalog_category_entity_decimal
catalog_category_entity_int
catalog_category_entity_text
catalog_category_entity_varchar
```

The `catalog/category` model also has a "flat catalog" feature in `System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Use Flat Catalog Category`.  With this enabled the `catalog/category` model will pull data from one of the flat categories

```
catalog_category_flat_store_*
```

Either way, you can use the `catalog/category` collection object to query this data any way you see fit, including the `addAttributeToFilter` method.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

$collection->addAttributeToFilter(
    'url_path', array('like' => 'apparel%')
);

foreach($collection as $item)
{
    var_dump($item->getData());
}
```

Comment: Alan, thank you for your response. I removed the second half of the question. I think I was just confused and the question came as such. I removed it. But yes you answered my question regarding the "use flat data" option.

Comment: When you use `Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId)->getProductCollection()` , this loads the same product collection object as `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->load()`, assuming there is only one category ($categoryId) and all of the products are in that category?

Comment: @Youn Mostly, look at the definition for getProductCollection in `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category.php`, you'll see a normal product collection instantiated, with a few default filters added.

Comment: How can we get a full list across all stores (like in admin menu categories) -- now when using Mage::getModel('catalog/category') it picks 1 store and uses that flat table ...